# Restrict helm to update or install if there are no changes/modification to your charts

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

Is there a way to restrict helm to install or update if there are no new changes or modifications detected in your charts?

Answer (score 2):

One way of doing this - take helm template on old and new chart and do a diff. Then proceed with updates only if there are changes.

Essentially,

```
values_diff=$(diff work-values/values.yaml work-values/values-prev.yaml | wc -l)
```

Where values.yaml and values-prev.yaml are outputs of helm template command on latest and previous charts.

Then you do

```
if [ $values_diff -gt 0 ]
then
    ....
```

And your update logic goes where dots are.

See full working sample here (note it has few extra things that you may omit) - https://github.com/relizaio/reliza-hub-integrations/blob/master/Helm-cd-with-Reliza/helm_configmap.yaml, which is part of my bigger tutorial here - https://worklifenotes.com/2021/05/22/helm-cd-with-reliza-hub-tutorial/

Comment: There is a [helm-diff plugin](https://github.com/databus23/helm-diff) that can help with this (it is a required dependency for Helmfile, if you're using that tool).

Answer (score 0):

I found a different way to do it. Wrote a small python script to list down files changed in the last 2 commits and then filtered out the apps which were modified.

Answer (score 0):

This is a great plugin for helm.

helm plugin install https://github.com/databus23/helm-diff

helm diff upgrade -n mynamespace myapp foo/myapp  -f custom-values.yaml

You could use it like so

```bash
#!/bin/bash
lines=$(helm diff upgrade -n mynamespace myapp foo/myapp  -f custom-values.yaml)
if [[ $(echo $lines | wc -l) > 0 ]]; then
  echo "$lines" | grep "^+\|^-"
  echo "Helm changes detected."
  echo "Running upgrade in 5."; sleep 5  helm upgrade --install -n mynamespace myapp foo/myapp  -f custom-values.yaml
fi
```

You can use terraform helm provider as well.

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/helm/latest/docs/resources/release